# When is $Pin_{\pm}(n)$ to the orthogonal $O(n)$ not onto or a universal covering space?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Could anyone explain why [this Wiki statement is true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_group):

> (1) In general the map from the Pin group to the orthogonal group is not onto or a universal covering space, but if the quadratic form is definite (and dimension is greater than 2), it is both.

Even though

> $$(2) \;\;\;Pin_{\pm}(n)/Z_2=O(n)$$

is always true? The (2) seems to imply for the map $Pin_{\pm}(n)\to O(n)$
is onto when $n\geq2$. How (1) and (2) are consistent to each other?

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are consistent because $\operatorname{Pin}_+(n) := \operatorname{Pin}(n, 0) \subset Cl_{n, 0}$ and $\operatorname{Pin}_-(n) := \operatorname{Pin}(0, n) \subset Cl_{0, n}$. That is, the groups $\operatorname{Pin}_{\pm}(n)$ are the pin groups in the definite case in which case the first statement says that they surject onto $O(n)$ (in fact they double cover it).